# CocoaPods installation error: "certificate B: certificate verify failed"

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I'm want to try Flutter. `flutter doctor` tells me that I need CocoaPods:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 11.6.1 20G224 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to
        your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
      instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

OK, all I need is CocoaPods!

I went to https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation and tried this first:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

This returned an error message:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Next I tried the sudo-less installation. I opened my `.bash_profile` and added two lines:

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then I ran `gem install cocoapods` again, without `sudo`:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

This returned the same error message:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I checked `rvm`, it seems to be installed correctly:

```
rvm -v
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

I don't know what a `server certificate B` is or how to fix it. What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

It updated Ruby certifications. I then had to update Ruby, then I installed CocoaPods. Rather than use `sudo` I installed the paths for CocoaPods in `.bash_profile`:

```
# for Cocoapods
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem 
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Then I installed CocoaPods:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

I ran `flutter doctor`:

```
flutter doctor           
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 11.6.1 20G224 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Yay!